Flymake displaying errors in echo-area
I want to prevent Flymake from displaying errors in mini-buffer/echo-area.
echo-area

Please describe the problem in detail. Depending on a screenshot is discouraged: you can use it to illustrate the description but it is not a substitute for a complete but concise description. Also note that the fact the the screenshot is incomplete makes it double inappropriate: we have no idea what it was that produced the message you show.
